# How can set value of javascript from html?

Tags: javascript, html, function

How I can set javascript value name from my html code?

```
    var mytime = new Date("Here I want set time value from html");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `value` of an `<input type="date">`:

```js
function date() {
    var mytime = new Date(document.getElementById("date").value);
    console.log(mytime);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date" />
<button onclick="date()">Make date</button>
```

Note: You need to enter a valid date.